# Probabilistically fair prize splitting for two-player coin toss

Tags: code-golf, probability-theory

### Introduction

> Adam (A) and Bubbler (B) are playing coin toss, where the one who wins 5 times first would win the prize of $32. If the game is aborted when the scores are `A:B = 4:3`, how should they distribute the prize? Assume the coin toss is fair, so the winning chance of either player is 1/2 for each game.

The answer is:

> Adam should take $24 and Bubbler should take $8. Possible cases are as follows:
>
> ```
> A wins (score 5:3, chance 1/2): A wins the prize
> B wins (score 4:4) then A wins (score 5:4, chance 1/4): A wins the prize
> B wins (score 4:4) then B wins (score 4:5, chance 1/4): B wins the prize
> ```
>
> Therefore, the chance of A winning is `3/4` and that of B is `1/4`.

### Challenge

In order to do the fair splitting of prizes, we should compute the chance of winning the prize for each player. Given the following information,

- `X`, how many times a player should win coin toss to win the prize
- `Wa`, how many times player A has already won
- `Wb`, how many times player B has already won

compute the chance of **player A** winning the prize.

### Input and output

You can assume the three input numbers `X`, `Wa`, `Wb` satisfy the following:

- All numbers are non-negative integers.
- `X > max(Wa, Wb)`, i.e. the game hasn't finished already.

You can choose to output a fraction or a floating-point number.

### Scoring and winning criterion

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. Shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
X Wa Wb => Expected output
--------------------------
5  4  3 =>  3/4  = 0.75
5  3  4 =>  1/4  = 0.25
1  0  0 =>  1/2  = 0.5
4  3  1 =>  7/8  = 0.875
4  2  1 => 11/16 = 0.6875
6  4  2 => 13/16 = 0.8125
```

Comment: Can `Wa` and `Wb` be taken as a complex number `Wa+j*Wb`, where `j` is the imaginary unit?

Comment: @LuisMendo That's OK. I/O is flexible as always.

Comment: May i output `6/8` instead of `3/4`?

Comment: @tsh Yes, it's fine.

Comment: @Bubbler What about binary or hex "decimals"?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 If it means writing 0.75 as \$ 0.11_2 \$, I don't think there's any problem allowing it.

Answer (score 9):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>36</s> 32 bytes

```r
function(X,A,B)pbeta(.5,X-A,X-B)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYq7CoAwEAR/xTIHq8Q8rLRIviKtigFBYxAt/PrzWKaZ2ZtzM7ac37I@@1VUQkCkumzPrDqP1AYhEp9zrcenMtK0Kg@PHk42EIIIBwstGDhCFGGlafn0MET8Aw)

The closed formula from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/197365/67312) suggested a natural probability distribution to use -- this is a Negative Binomial with \$X - W_b - 1\$ failures and \$X - W_a\$ successes, i.e., the probability that there are \$X - W_a\$ "successes" before there are \$X - W_b\$ "failures".

Further identities reduce the CDF of the negative binomial to the CDF of a beta distribution or in terms of the (regularized) incomplete beta function.

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 44 bytes

```
Binomial[g=#-#2+t,k]~Sum~{k,0,t=#-#3-1}/2^g&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73ykzLz83MzEnOt1WWVfZSLtEJzu2Lrg0t646W8dApwQkaKxrWKtvFJeu9j@gKDOvJFqjWlm5VkHXTiEtWlk5VlPNwcGhutpUR8FER8G4VkcBxDQG8kBMQx0FAyACMU3AooZQphGUaQbWZlRbG/sfAA)

Not super short, but uses an algorithm that might lead to shorter code in other languages: the code calculates the sum of binomial coefficients
[image: formula]
which is the closed form for the result of the path-counting algorithms in other solutions.

Comment: [33 bytes](https://tio.run/##LctBCoUwDATQqwQC8oXo11bdKcUTuC9dRFF0oQvprvTs1RYhMG8GcrLd15PtsXDY@jCulnXZEvdYoKA5hjT/NDPNJgvTfVxW/xyih2KATSOaPFNKOdcSNATSE0TKt0XWBNV7kU1a64/iY5fehPcmPA)

Comment: Alternately, this is the CDF of a negative binomial distribution if that's at all helpful.

Comment: @Giuseppe That's a great approach, you should post it as an answer! Note that you can shave off 1 more byte by making the denominator `a~Beta~b`.

Comment: Sure, [done](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/197659/67312).

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>62</s>  56 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,a,b:a<n>b and(f(n,a+1,b)+f(n,a,b+1))/2.or a>b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7RCoMwDEWf16/IWxXDNK1VGdMfER9ahmyw1TEGY1/v0jih9KbnhKTP7/u6RLOuc3/3j3DxENFjOPlzHAL4eMnmjElBGPJCSgwF5XlpjssL/BDWmTPix@MnwC3CODqs0U7IabHmJKyw4mSKJGkkG@4z03RSh@frFt/7ENT9oDGtkmeutNbKAdQAFvqB75LLHqpj6xK3SSVOOzdOEUCVzsbNxp2SGUCC27LbcNeKMH9BVFIjokmmkc1GjN1NR7yD/7X@AA)

Returns a float. Uses a recursive approach.

Ungolfed:

```python
def f(n,wa,wb):
    if wa<n and wb<n:
        return (f(n, wa+1, wb) + f(n, wa, wb+1))/2.0
    elif wa==n: return 1
    else: return 0
```

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 24 bytes

```
x"TF1GEZ^!Ys@+1G<~s]P>Ym
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v0IpxM3Q3TUqTjGy2EHb0N2mrjg2wC4y9/9/M65oEwWjWAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8L9CKcTN0N01Kk4xsthB29Ddpq44NsAuMve/S1RFyH9TrmgTBeNYLiBtrGASy2XIFW2gYBDLZQLiG4JpIxBtBlJnFAsA).

Input is `X`, then `[Wa Wb]`. Output is a floating-point number.

#### How it works

This enumerates all possible paths of length `2*X` that emanate from the initial conditions defined by `Wa` and `Wb`. This length is enough to ensure that someone wins (actually length `2*X-Wa-Wb-1` would suffice).

For each path, the code determines who wins as follows. It keeps a cumultive sum of score for each player, computes how long each player has had score `X` or more along the path, and the winner is the player who has maintained that condition for longer. This is equivalent to, but golfier than, asking who reached `X` earlier in that path. Note that there can be no ties.

The result is the proportion of paths in which player A wins.

```
x      % Implicit input: X. Delete it
"      % Implicit input: [Wa Wb]. For each
  TF   %   Push [0 1]
  1G   %   Push X
  E    %   Multiply by 2
  Z^   %   Cartesian power of [0 1] with exponent 2*X. Gives a matrix with each
       %   Cartesian tuple contained in a row. Rows are in lexicographical order
       %   Each column is a step in the path, containing 1 if the user wins or 0
       %   otherwise
  !    %   Transpose. Each tuple is now a column
  Ys   %   Cumulative sum of each column. This is the accumulated gain along each
       %   path. Note that the matrix has more than one row; otherwise the
       %   cumulative sum would work along the single row
  @    %   Push Wa (first iteration) or Wb (second iteration)
  +    %   Add. This gives the total accumulated score along each path, including
       %   the initial score
  1G   %   Push X
  <~   %   Not less than?
  s    %   Sum of each column. This indicates for how long the score X has been
       %   reached, or exceeded, in each path
]      % End
P      % Flip. This reverses the results for player B, to reflect the fact that
       % the paths of the two users are complementary: user B increases their 
       % score when user A doesn't. Reversing the vector is equivalent to
       % replacing each path by its complement, thanks to the lexicographical
       % order of the Cartesian tuples
>      % Greater than? This indicates for which paths player A wins
Ym     % Mean. Implicit display
```

Comment: Poorly golfed, but [14 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X880M1M3xD1TV8FYJTL9/39TLhMuYwA) using the incomplete beta function, as it's the CDF of the negative binomial.

Comment: (and the beta distribution too!)

Comment: @Giuseppe You should definitely post that! A little shorter: https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X880M1M3qtZTJTL9/39TrmgTBeNYAA

Comment: Ah, `Z}`, that's what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>17 16</s>  14 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-2 thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

```
_µS’2*ḶB§‘>ḢÆm
```

A dyadic Link accepting the end-goal, `X`, on the left and the current state `[Wa,Wb]` on the right which yields a float of A's chances.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9qZWxsef//X8K1U@KAmTIq4bi2QsKn4oCYPuG4osOGbf///zb/NCwy)**

#### How?

Forms all binary strings of \$X-Wa+X-Wb-1\$ bits, treating 1s as a win for A and 0s as a win for B. Identifies those with at least \$X-Wa\$ 1s and takes the mean (i.e. winCount / total).

```
_µS’2*ḶB§‘>ḢÆm - Link: X, [Wa, Wb]
_              - subtract (vectorises)   -> V=[X-Wa, X-Wb]
 µ             - start a new monadic chain, f(V)
  S            - sum                          X-Wa+X-Wb
   ’           - decrement                    X-Wa+X-Wb-1
    2*         - two raised to that power     2^(X-Wa+X-Wb-1)
      Ḷ        - lowered range                [0,1,2,3,4,...,2^(X-Wa+X-Wb-1)-1]
       B       - to binary (vectorises)       [[0],[1],[1,0],[1,1],[1,0,0],...,[1,1,...,1]]
        §      - sums                         [0,1,1,2,1,...,X-Wa+X-Wb-1]
         ‘     - increment (vectorises)       [1,2,2,3,2,...,X-Wa+X-Wb]
           Ḣ   - head (V)                     X-Wa
          >    - greater than? (vectorises) A=[0>=X-Wa,1>=X-Wa, ...]
            Æm - mean                         A's win probability
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Jelly, but isn't `µS÷L` just `Æm`?

Comment: Indeed sum/length is mean - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 11 bytes

```
.5ii-Z}3$Yg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X880M1M3qtZYJTL9/39TrmgTBeNYAA)

This is a port of my [R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/197372/67312). Thanks to Luis Mendo for helping golf it down.

```
.5     # push .5
ii     # push both inputs, X, and [Wa, Wb]
-      # subtract, so stack is [.5, [X - Wa, X - Wb]]
Z}     # split array onto stack
       # so stack is [.5, X - Wa, X - Wb]
3$Yg   # (regularized) incomplete beta function with 3 arguments
       # implicitly output the probability
```

Also a nice short Octave solution:

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 27 bytes

```matlab
@(X,A,B)betainc(.5,X-A,X-B)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z@mYKugp6f330EjQsdRx0kzKbUkMTMvWUPPVCdC1xGInTT/p2mY6pjoGGv@BwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
_Ä’Żc@SH⁹¡ʋ/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9qZWxsef//X8OE4oCZxbtjQFNI4oG5wqHKiy////80/zEsMg)

A dyadic link taking the number to win as left argument and the coin tosses won so far by players b and a respectively as the right argument.

Based on [the formula described by @GregMartin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/197365/42248) so be sure to upvote his answer too!

### Explanation

```
_            | Subtract
 Ä           | Cumulative sum
  ’          | Decrease by 1
          ʋ/ | Reduce using the following as a dyad (left argument represents X - Wb - 1; right argument represents 2X - Wa - Wb - 1)
   Ż         | - Range from 0..left argument
    c@       | - Number of combinations for each using right argument as n
      S      | - Sum
       H⁹¡   | - Half the number of times indicated by the right argument
```

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
MḢ’¹2Ṭ+Çɗ€ÆmƊ}Ị?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVQAq/9qZWxsef//TeG4ouKAmcK5MuG5rCvDh8mX4oKsw4Ztxop94buKP///4bik4oCZw5gu4bmX4bijU31TPeG4osKlyovGh8KnPOKBuMOGbUP/Miw0LDY)

An alternative Jelly answer that uses a recursive approach. A full program that takes as its argument a list of `Wb, Wa, n` and returns the answer as a float.

### Explanation

```
M                | Indices of maximum
 Ḣ               | Head
  ’              | Subtract 1
              Ị? | If absolute of this less than or equal to one:
   ¹             | Then: Return this value
            Ɗ}   | Else following as a monad applied to the original argument to this link:
    2            | - Literal 2
        ɗ€       | - Apply the following to the implicit range 1..2 with the original argument as the right argument
     Ṭ           |   - Convert to logical list with 1 at the relevant index
      +          |   - Add to the original argument (effectively increments Wa for 1 and Wb for 2)
       Ç         |   - Call this link with the updated argument
          Æm     | - Arithmetic mean
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 32 bytes

```
Beta[.5,a=#-#2,b=#-#3]/a~Beta~b&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73ym1JDFaz1Qn0VZZV9lIJwlEGcfqJ9aBJOqS1P4HFGXmlURrVCsr1yro2imkRSsrx2qqOTg4VFeb6iiY6CgY1@oogJjGQB6IaaijYABEIKYJWNQQyjSCMs3A2oxqa2P/AwA)

Yet [another port](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/197413/67312) of the negative binomial CDF approach suggested by [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/197365/67312).

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 36 bytes

```
Ｎθ≔Ｅ⁻θＮ⁰ηＦＥ⁻θＮ¹ＦＬη«≔⊘⁺ι§ηκι§≔ηκι»Ｉ⊟η
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY2xDoIwGIRneYp//P@kJmqMCxNxkUQMr1Ch0sZaoC3ExPjstSgDk8MNl/vurpLcVi3XIeSmG/xleFyFxZ7SJHNONQYL3mGhzOCwZ7BkiBhsomRkb62F/@SWCL7UWZjGS5TRv5LVfHLiehQ1ljqWFYPM56YWT5QM7jS1VfyY2WX2C95JaZXxeOTOY9l20zalIRxgD7uwHvUH) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input the desired number of coin tosses.

```
Ｅ⁻θＮ⁰η
```

Calculate the number of remaining tosses player A needs, and create an array of that length of zeros. The (1-indexed) `n`th entry represents that the probability of `A` winning given that he still has `n` tosses remaining and `B` initially has no tosses remaining.

```
ＦＥ⁻θＮ¹
```

Loop over the number of remaining tosses player B needs. Start with the probability of `A` winning given that he still has `0` tosses remaining and `B` has `m` tosses remaining as `1`.

```
ＦＬη«
```

Loop over the probabilities.

```
≔⊘⁺ι§ηκι
```

Average the current probability (representing the case where `A` wins this toss) with the probability from the array (representing the case where `B` wins this toss).

```
§≔ηκι
```

Save this new probability in the array.

```
»Ｉ⊟η
```

Output the last probability calculated, which is for `n=X-Wa,m=X-Wb`.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 44 bytes

```javascript
a=>g=(b,c)=>a==b||a>c&&(g(b+1,c)+g(b,c+1))/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7daoQwEEbvfYq52p2gTYzWHyjxrk/RLWxM1VqyKkaWhW6f3SZRIYThnHzf5EfepVFzPy0vw/jVrK1Ypag6gXWkiKikEPXzKSt1OmGHdcgtDTsnQ04IS9alMYuSpgEB1yADeAVIQVT2ZnYUENMiczx1ynF@8CQLOEDszsaTjWeB7wDuccHKDZeFF8kuOGc89yJ3JvebE2/Sw5Tc7rjSZe5vSKiZdL/g@TKcSXD8mrbj/C7VN2qX/A0A7nKGDxlBHYH6tC16z7GLCZkt0b1qMI4gJfQmJ3y4XPggbzaqxsGMuqF67HBviKBFSdCNxL75I@s/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 77 bytes

```java
double f(int x,int a,int b){return(a<x&b<x?f(x,a+1,b)+f(x,a,b+1):a>b?2:0)/2;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/RaoMwFIbv@xSHgiPBrFPb7cLW9Ql21YsNpBcnVUs6q5JEcYjP7tJohxQGyTk/3wn/@XPBBp8vyfdQ1TwXJzjlqBR8oCigWwAojdrQISnNOIWMiEJDy24VbeW0k6muZUFw1z7xXbvPSMvQ9RmnrpWMuz4N8Z3vg9CjL8G2H4zxtG7yb0qRwNUsJQctRXGOj4DyrKjNAGAWxUfDdKq0gmiiAB28MtgwWEPP5mht6Bz5DDxz5mhjX/kPKHhAb9Y@uKN@a1tWSiANSpsnHFPRv1CHH6XT66qs9aoyf9EZWX5FTsLgE8fGbVNVLnTkKKdYMmsRe8dJ@HcRGJGRf4eUjnn6xe32wy8)

### Credits

- Port of [Chas Brown's Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/197355/16236).
- -1 byte, thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

### Iterative version, 89 bytes

```java
(x,a,b)->{int r=0,i=1<<x*2>>a-~b,n=i;for(;i-->0;)r+=x.bitCount(i)<x-a?0:1;return 1.*r/n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZFBa8IwFMfvfoqHICQu7drqdjCmO@y0w9jBwwbSQ1qjxGkqSSod0n31LqZ1E2EQeC@/vPzf@ydbfuTBdvXZHqp8JwsodtwYeOVSwWkAIJUVes0LAYvDTlo4wVu@FYUFc96iF3e8ERpqApeU/6U5ptA4EWO5ddKdgr8IrEU14STHQXpyPUCziEgWz@f1OElTHnznRDFJ16VGVAZBGlGs71gd5tI@l5WySOJ5HfCnaBZTLWylFcThWN8r2rTUtezd9J2PpVzB3nlCC6ul2iwz4HpjsLfoTS4zx6ww1gDrKTizDwSmBCbQkGs0cfQaxQQit67R1FfFNyi5QY9ePrmghvrgTAM6cu3nmXVT4d@hFl/Gin1YVjY8OC92jYYfbLQi8M67kPvgn5mNzEgNiZdYRlmfxJckyfq6sPvNf8sw7iY7f2YzaNof)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 45 bytes

```
{m:g/\-//$_}o{[X+] .[1],|(^2 xx+^.sum)}o&[X-]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OtcqXT9GV19fJb42vzo6QjtWQS/aMFanRiPOSKGiQjtOr7g0V7M2Xy06Qjf2vzVXcWKlQhpIiY5RrA6QNohVSMsv4tIw1VEw0VEw1tQBM42BPBDTUEfBAIhATBOwqCGUaQRlmoG1GWn@BwA)

Takes arguments as `f((a, b), x)`. Counts `2x-a-b-1`-bit numbers with popcount less than `x-b`.

#### Explanation

```perl6
                                        &[X-]  # Compute a-x, b-x
             {                        }o  # Feed into block
                          ^2            # Range 0..1
                             xx         # repeated
                               +^.sum   # ~(a-x+b-x) = 2x-a-b-1 times
                        |(           )  # flattened
                   .[1]   # b-x
              [X+]     ,  # Cartesian product with addition,
                          # computes popcount(i)-(x-b) for all i
{          }o  # Feed into block
 m:g/\-/  # Regex match '-' chars in string representation,
          # counting negative values
        /$_  # Divide by number of values
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
-¤sO<oL<2вO›ÅA
```

Inputs in the format and order `[Wa, Wb], X`.

Port of [*@JonathanAllan*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/197356/52210).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f99CSYn@bfB8bowub/B817Drc6vj/f7SJjnEslykA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/m5mKvpJCYl6KgZO/pYl@spPCobRKQ/V/30JJif5t8HxujC5v8HzXsOtzq@F/nf7SJjnEslylXtLGOCZg20DGI5TIE8Q1juUy4oo2gtImOUSyXGQA).

A port of [*@GregMartin*'s formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/197365/52210) would be 16 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage):

```
-¤sO<UFXNc}OXoz*
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f99CSYn@bULcIv@Ra/4j8Kq3//6NNdIxjuUwB) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/m5mKvpJCYl6KgZO/pYl@spPCobRKQ/V/30JJif5tQtwi/5Fr/iPwqrf86/6NNdIxjuUy5oo11TMC0gY5BLJchiG8Yy2XCFW0EpU10jGK5zAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
-               # Subtract each value of the first (implicit) input-pair from the second
                # (implicit) input: [X-Wa,X-Wb]
 ¤              # Push its last value (without popping the list itself): X-Wb
  s             # Swap to get the list again
   O            # Sum them together: 2X-Wa-Wb
    <           # Decrease it by 1: 2X-Wa-Wb-1
     o          # Take 2 to the power this: 2^(2X-Wa-Wb-1)
      L         # Pop and push a list in the range [1,2^(2X-Wa-Wb-1)]
       <        # Decrease each value by 1 to make it [1,2^(2X-Wa-Wb-1))
        2в      # Convert each to a binary-list
          O     # Sum each inner list of bits
           ›    # Check for each if it's larger than the X-Wb: [X-Wb>1,X-Wb>2,...]
            ÅA  # Take the arithmetic mean of that list
                # (which is output implicitly as result)

-¤sO<           # The same as above
     U          # Pop and store this 2X-Wa-Wb-1 in variable `X`
      F         # Loop `N` in the range [0,X-Wb):
         c      #  Take the binomial coefficient (a.k.a. number of combinations) of:
       X        #   The 2X-Wa-Wb-1 of variable `X`
        N       #   And the loop-index `N`
      }O        # After the loop: sum all values on the stack
        X       # Push 2X-Wa-Wb-1 from variable `X` again
         o      # Take 2 to the power this: 2^(2X-Wa-Wb-1)
          z     # Take the invert of this: 1/(2^(2X-Wa-Wb-1))
           *    # And multiply it with the sum
                # (after which this is output implicitly as result)
```